# Backbone svg cube events getting disabled on flip

Tags: css, backbone.js, svg

Just a bit of trivia: I have started using backbone just a month back and svg about a week back. Basically am still learning.

I mainly have a cube. On load the front face has a circle divided into sectors. Each sector is clickable. On clicking each sector the cube flips 90 degrees right and that particular sector is zoomed and displayed there.

Now there is a slider on the zoomed sector ranging from 0-10. This I have created again using svg circles on a line equidistantly. The problem is that the circles must be clickable so that the value on which it is clicked should be captured.

But once the cube flips none of the events are firing. I have been struggling with this for 3 days now but no luck. Any help from anybody please.

I understand that the delegateEvents() method needs to be called somewhere, but where am not able to make out. Or is it the css transforms that are disabling the events, I don't understand???

Below is my code:

The js file

```
var CircleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: this.model,
    xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",

    events: {
        'click path': 'handleClick',
    },

    handleClick: function(ev) {
        var id = $(ev.currentTarget).attr('id');

        var el = this.$el;
        model = this.model;

        var xAngle = 0, yAngle = -90;

        // Cube flips here 

        (document.getElementById('cube')).style.webkitTransform = "rotateX(" + xAngle + "deg) rotateY(" + yAngle + "deg)";

        // view to display the zoomed sector

        var secView = new SectorView({el: $('#circleEdit2'), model: model, value: value, id: id});
        secView.render();
    },

    render: function(model) {
        // Code to draw svg circle with 12 clickable sectors goes here 
        // On clicking any sector cube flips and zoomed sector is displayed there 
        // This is working perfectly

        el.html($("#face1").html());

        return el;
    }
})

var SectorView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: this.model,
    id: 0,
    value: 0,

    xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",

    events: {
        'click circle': 'handleDots'
    },

    handleDots: function(ev) {
        var id = $(ev.currentTarget).attr('id');
        var numID = parseInt(id);

        alert("Click Event Called");
    },

    render: function() {
        var id = this.id;
        var el = this.$el;
        model = this.model;

        // Code to draw zoomed Sector ranging from 0-10 goes here 
        // method to draw slider using svg circles on a line equidistantly 
        // On clicking each circle value should be captured 
        // Here click event is not firing but all graphics are displayed correctly 

        this.drawSlider(el, id, winWidth/2, oRadius, value, (winWidth/3 - oRadius/4.7));

        $("#face2").html(this.$el);

        $("#radios").css("top", winWidth/3.5);
        $("#radios").css("left", left);

        this.delegateEvents();
    }
})
```

The HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="circleEditTool.css">
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.2\jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.2\ui\jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.2\ui\jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.2\ui\jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.2\ui\jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.2\ui\jquery.ui.slider.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="cube">
        <div class="face one" id="face1">
            <svg id="circleEdit1"> </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="face two" id="face2">
            <svg id="circleEdit2"> </svg>
            <div id="radios">
                <input name='typeOfArea' type='radio' value="Strength" checked>Strength</input>
                <input name='typeOfArea' type='radio' value="OK">OK</input>
                <input name='typeOfArea' type='radio' value="Weakness">Weakness</input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </br></br>
    <script src="circleEditTool2.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The css:

```
#experiment {
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 300px;
}

#cube {
    position: center;
    margin: auto;
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s linear;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.face {
    position: absolute;
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
#cube .one {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(200px);
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#cube .two {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(350px);
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: You really need to simplify this till you get the simplest possible amount of code that shows the issue. It's unlikely anyone will help you till you do.

Comment: Please consider also creating a jsfiddle.net, it increase the change of response.

Comment: Have simplified the code. Thank you for the suggestion, hope somebody helps now